# Virtual directories as DB queries

Tags: mysql, database, apache, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a site, e.g. site.com
I would like users to be able to access it in their locale at site.com/somecity
This is similar to craigslist, but they do it with subdomains e.g. sfbay.craigslist.org
Using Apache HTTP server.
MySql for DB.

If you can provide a brief explanation and perhaps links to more thorough discussions, I would be quite interested in learning. I'm developing a web-app and wonder if I should focus some time to read up on Apache, or should I focus more of my time on server-side programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not really a programming question, but...

I'd focus on the programming, since ideally it would be applicable to which ever server you end up deploying on. Reading up on how to configure Apache will only help you if you end up deploying on Apache.